# Redirect from DocuSign PowerForm to my site

Tags: docusignapi

I'm trying to integrate DocuSign to my website. With the DocuSign Power Form I'm kind of successful to integrate. When a button is clicked in my website user is redirected to the Docusign Power Form. But what I need to do is redirect the user back to my site once the signing is done.

Is it something I can do with the Power Form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control where a user is directed after a PowerForm.  It uses the values set under Preferences -> Features -> "In session landing pages".  Typically these values are overridden when using the API but they do work for PowerForms.

Whether or not you should use PowerForms vs. API depends on your Use Case.  For example, a very static document that you want anyone who visits your site to be able to sign could work.  It's certainly a lot easier than API integration.  However anything more complicated would probably be better solved through the API.

Answer (score 0):

It is let reply but it can help for other guy's

Firstly you can choose direct way instead of email. but keep in mind email is more secure then direct way.

Then you can changed these landing pages from the Classic DocuSign Experience by going to Preferences, clicking Features under the Account Administration section and clicking the In-session Landing pages link under Advanced Options. You can enter your website link to redirect back to the website on each action such as completing the Power-form or declining to sign. When user submit the power-form it will redirect to your given website action.

Answer (score -2):

I do not believe you can control the re-directs when you use a PowerForm.  Instead, the optimized and recommended best-practice approach if you want to Embed DocuSign into your website or app is to use the DocuSign API and open the singing experience in an `iFrame` (or `Webview` if doing mobile).

Check out the [DocuSign Developer Center](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center) where you can create a free developer sandbox and start using the APIs in minutes.  Also make sure to check out the API Tools page under the Quick Start section where you'll find the API Walkthroughs with code samples.  The bottom three explain Embedded Sending, Embedded Signing, and how to Embed the DocuSign Console itself.

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-tools

Chose whichever language you need, copy the code, replace the variables at the top and run!

Comment: Thanks @Ergin. I've little confusion with using API. First of all I have a pro account but still I need to have a developer account for integrator key, RIght? Do I have to control everything from dev account then what's the pro account for? Why "Demonstration Document Only" appears at the top of every page in signing document?[SEE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/xyxi7uo18msl2mg/Demonstration_document.jpg?dl=0) Someone says about certification.Once certification is done would I be able to use my pro account for API purpose? I wonder If i gotta have the same credentials for pro and dev account.

Comment: Hi @efat, yes you need a developer account to create an integrator key that you can migrate to the production environment.  To migrate your IK you need to go through the [API Certification](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/go-live/preparation) process.  Once your key is enabled in production you can then use your production account credentials (ie your Professional plan you purchased) to login and use the integration.  The developer account itself stays in the demo environment.

Comment: This answer is no longer correct. See [Amit's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55105683/64904)