# DocuSign API to obtain the response (signed) documents from Power Form

Tags: docusignapi

We are using Power Form to create a signing document in an envelop for our clients to sign our contract.

After our client completed signing (response to) the document, can we get any call back event and get the client signed(completed) document (either Stream or URL) from docSign?

I was trying to use the sample code below to download the document, but it only gets the template PDF (no data) from the envelop not the client completed document.

```
EnvelopesApi envelopesApi = new EnvelopesApi(apiClient.Configuration);

var docStream = envelopesApi.GetDocument(accountId, envelopeId, "combined");

using (var stream = File.Create(@"c:\temp\docu38.pdf"))
      {
           docStream.CopyTo(stream);
      }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above call will work fine to retrieve signed document if you have the envelopeId available with you for each envelope created using Powerform.

There are different ways to get EnvelopeIds back from DocuSign for Powerform scenario:

- If you are using Direct Powerform (no Email validation) and one
  signer scenario, then you need to Create In-Session landing page in
  DS Account as explained in [Configure In-Session landing

  pages](https://support.docusign.com/en/articles/How-do-I-specify-a-URL-to-redirect-to-when-a-Powerform-is-completed),
  configure return/callback URL like    https://www.google.com?, where 
  www.google.com is your callback App URL and when callback will happen
  you will see some query parameters like below:

  https://www.google.com/?env=b807a0fc-fc80-445f-9740-38e0e5f0200c&pf=c4b09cfb-8264-4fe7-a35d-554294f99445&r=50dd1f38-4242-4d47-8ddb-f73c03db929e

  where env is the envelopeId and now you can use this envelopeId to
  get the signed document
- If you are using Direct PowerForm with multiple Signers or if you are
  using Email Powerform (Selected Require Email Validation checkbox in
  Powerform Configuration) then you need configure Destination URLs in
  Branding as explained
  [here](https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/advanced-branding-configuration.htm)
  with the return/callback URL like https://www.google.com, where
  www.google.com is your callback App URL and in response DocuSign will
  also send envelopeId in the query parameter and now you can use this
  envelopeId to
        get the signed document
- Last way and the most recommended is to use [DocuSign
  Connect](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/connect),
  its like a Pub-Sub Architecture where you will develop and host a
  WebService which can accept a POST call and an XML input. And you
  will configure the same WebService in DocuSign and also you will
  configure Trigger Events in DocuSign, informing DocuSign whats your
  interested events when you want DocuSign to push an XML notification
  to your WebService. Once that trigger events happen on your envelope
  then DocuSign will push an XML message with envelopeId and status of
  the envelope, upon receiving the XML message you can call /documents
  API with envelopeId to download the Signed document. Also if your
  documents are not huge then you can DocuSign to send you signed
  Document in the XML as Base64 format as well, this is one of the
  configuration in DocuSign Connect settings while configuring your
  Webservice.

Comment: Thank you very much, Amit!!  This is very helpful and I will give it a try.  Again, what I meant about the "signed" document, is the document signed by users. For example, in my envelop I have one "template" document, then if there are 10 people sign on it, I will get 10 signed documents.

Comment: No, if you have 10 recipients or Signers on a Single Envelope which has one document then you have one Signed Document only, not 10 Signed Documents. Each recipient on an envelope is part of the workflow, when All Recipients have completed the signing then you get Envelope as Completed and that document has signature or data from each signature on that one document. If any recipient has not completed the signature before expiry of the envelope then envelope is in In-Progress state, but still only Document where all recipients have to take some actions on the document.

Comment: so if I have one contract document for my investors to sign (I don't know how many investors), I need to create an envelope for each of mine users?